# Skipping test steps in testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am following POM approach with Testng for designing my framework . Consider a scenario wherein the test case got failed in the nth test step inside a @Test method.Can anyone suggest how can I skip the remaining test steps(from n+1 onwards)?

Since I am automating the manual test cases, each @Test belongs to 1 test case and so I cannot split up the steps into multiple @Test methods. When the test step is failed, it needs to skip the next steps in that @Test method and proceed to the next test case.

Also I need the count of test steps skipped in the result.

Kindly help.

Comment: You can use dependOnMethod attribute in testNg

Comment: try to write those cases inside try and catch block.

Comment: You have to define what test step failure means in your case? Usually means  AssertionError has happened, then the rest of the code in the test method is skipped automatically.

Comment: It can be any error. Like, any object identification fails, or assertion error, any exception.

Comment: If your script/test case throws an exception, the rest of the test steps in the script/test case will be skipped automatically due to the failure/exception. I guess I don't understand what you are asking. The count of test steps skipped is going to be a bit more challenging. You would have to know how many steps are in the text case and assign that to a variable. As the test progresses, each successful test step would subtract 1 from the steps. If an exception/failure occurs, you could print the current value of remaining steps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are basically looking for something around what a BDD tool such as Cucumber provides you. Cucumber lets you create a `.feature` file which contains one or more `scenario` (You can visualize each of your `scenario` to be one `@Test` annotated test method).

You could then leverage one of the Cucumber integrations i.e.,

Choose either JUnit (or)
Choose TestNG integration

and let one of these run your BDD tests.

Here when a particular step fails, then all subsequent steps would be aborted (which is what you are asking for)

Outside of Cucumber, I dont think you can have this done via any other mechanism. The reporting needs (such as how many steps were skipped etc.,) can be fulfilled by any cucumber based reports.

You should start from here : http://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/